# How to change treemap color scale on "Dash example - modal treemap"

Tags: python, plotly-dash, treemap

I try to change color scale on example (modal treemap).

[https://dash-example-index.herokuapp.com/modal-treemap](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I added color definition to treemap call but it does not change the color. Where I need to put my modification to make it active.

```
fig = px.treemap(
            dff, path=[px.Constant("all"), "Segment", "Region"], 
            values="profit_derived", 
            **color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn[::-1]**
            
                )
```

Example of dff:

```
,profit_derived,Segment,Region,ship_date
0,5.4,Corporate,North Asia,2014-08-19
1,2.3616,Consumer,South,2014-04-17
2,3.401,Consumer,West,2012-10-17
3,22.92,Consumer,Caribbean,2013-06-15
4,6.9,Corporate,North Asia,2014-09-18
5,42.3,Home Office,EMEA,2013-10-27
6,101.64,Consumer,North,2011-08-15
```

Comment: Please add sample of dff.

Comment: Now added first 7 rows from dff

Comment: Could you please explain how you want to assign colors to the treemap?

Comment: Now theme seems to be blue-red-green. I want to change it green-yellow-red. Also it seems that colors are very discrete. I like to see smooth changes.

Comment: The change of colors based on profit_derived, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `color_continuous_scale` along with `color` to be able to see the impact of the colors. You can use the following:

```
fig = px.treemap(
            dff, path=[px.Constant("all"), "Segment", "Region"], 
            values="profit_derived", 
            color="profit_derived",
            color_continuous_scale="RdYlGn"
            
                )
fig.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]